# Complex where clause in QueryDSL

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Any one help for this Mysql query to QueryDSL Predicates?

i'm using QueryDSL 2.9.0 + Spring-data-jpa 1.3.2 + hibernate

```
select itemkey, issuedt, writedate
from Taxinvoice
where
DATEDIFF(writeDate,ifnull((select closeDate from IssueCloseDate where YearMonth = date_format(writedate,'%Y%m'))
,Date_Add(Date_Add(writeDate,interval 10-day(writedate) DAY), interval 1 MONTH))) > 0
```

Can it be done? :(

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be expressed in JPA, you will need to use SQL for this. Querydsl supports SQL via Querydsl SQL and Querydsl JPA native queries.